# PyTest: test which function was called in the if statement

Tags: python, python-2.7, testing, pytest

I have a function, which considers three different cases and for each case calls a different function, like in the example below

```
def my_fun(input):
 if input == 1:
    fun1()
 if input == 2:
    fun2()
 if input == 3:
    fun3()
```

I would like to write a test for function `my_fun` using `py.test`, but I don't know how I can test if the proper function was called for a given input?

Comment: As long as the output is correct, do you really care which function was called?

Comment: @fmarc Well, of course I can test for three possible inputs and check the outputs, but this means I have to run all three functions fun1, fun2, fun3 and I'm just looking for a more elegant way to do that

Comment: Would it also work for you to just write tests for fun1/2/3 directly? my_fun() contains very little code, so in any case you gain very little from writing a test for it.

Comment: @Ziva please checkout my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/37583992/4988742. Will that work for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all fun1(), fun2(), and fun3() return results I'd go with parametrization.

```
# Here an example of functions to be tested

def fun1():
    return 1
def fun2():
    return 2
def fun3():
    return 3

def my_fun(input):
    if input == 1:
        return fun1()
    if input == 2:
        return fun2()
    if input == 3:
        return fun3()
```

Here in the test matrix. The expected result is also a call to a function under test so you can match the function call in the test (as you asked in the question):

```
# Parametrized test
import pytest

@pytest.mark.parametrize("test_input, expected", [(1, fun1()), (2, fun2()), (3, fun3())])
# ---------------------------------------
# test_input |   1    |   2    |   3    |
# ---------------------------------------
#   expected | fun1() | fun2() | fun3() |
# ---------------------------------------
def test_my_fun(test_input, expected):
    assert my_fun(test_input) == expected
```

Test run:

```
mac: py.test -v test_parametrization.py
=================================================================================== test session starts ====================================================================================
platform darwin -- Python 2.7.11, pytest-2.9.1, py-1.4.31, pluggy-0.3.1 -- /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
cachedir: .cache
rootdir: /Users/user/Repos/playground, inifile:
plugins: hidecaptured-0.1.2, instafail-0.3.0
collected 3 items

test_parametrization.py::test_my_fun[1-1] PASSED
test_parametrization.py::test_my_fun[2-2] PASSED
test_parametrization.py::test_my_fun[3-3] PASSED

================================================================================= 3 passed in 0.01 seconds =================================================================================
```

Answer (score 5):

As @fmarc commented, which function is called is less important than testing that `my_fun` does the right thing. But, you can mock each of the three functions, then test that the correct one was called independently of what each function actually does. (Note that `mock` is a 3rd-party module in Python 2 that you'll need to install; it is available the standard library in Python 3.3(?) as `unittest.mock`.)

One simple example:

```
import mock

def test_my_fun():
    with mock.patch('fun1', wraps=fun1) as mock_fun1:
        with mock.patch('fun2', wraps=fun2) as mock_fun2:
            with mock.patch('fun3', wraps=fun3) as mock_fun3:
                my_fun(1)
                mock_fun1.assert_called_with()
                mock_fun2.assert_not_called()
                mock_fun3.assert_not_called()
```

Check the documentation of your installation of `mock` to see which methods are supported.

Comment: Note that since Py2.7 you can use multiple context managers in one with-statement. Not very readable in this case :-), but saves indentation.

Comment: Oh, right. I've been stuck in 2.6 for so long, I forgot when that got added.

Comment: There's also [pytest-mock](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-mock) which gives you a `mocker` fixture which (IMHO) simplifies this a bit, as you can simply do `mock_fun1 = mock.match('fun1', wraps=fun1)` etc., and the fixture will take care of cleaning up after the test.

Answer (score -6):

Why multiple if statements and not elif? They conditions are mutually exclusive so why waste another check ? But anyway, how about dummy prints, like so:

```
def my_fun(input):
    if input == 1:
        fun1()
        print("Function 1 executed ?")
    elif input == 2:
        fun2()
        print("Function 2 executed ?")
    elif input == 3:
        fun3()
        print("Function 3 executed ?")
```

If i had enough reputation i would just comment btw. #JustWannaGetTo50

Comment: He said with `py.test`.

Comment: you should never rely on print statements to determine if your test passed